# karate.match with contains is not working

Tags: karate

I'm trying to do this example (https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature line 556):

```
* def foo = { a: 1, b: 'foo' }
* def res = karate.match("foo contains { a: '#number' }")
* match res == { pass: true, message: null }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
javascript evaluation failed: karate.match("foo contains { a: '#number' }"), TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod Map com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.match(Object,Object)] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 1
```

Do you know what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old version of Karate. Please upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Peter Thomas!!